# morphing in iphone

Tags: iphone, opengl, core-animation, morphing

is there a (simple) way to make a morphing (faces as a typical example)
using core animation or openGL?

Answer (score 2):

no, there's no simple way to do this. You can do a cross-fade (fade out one while fading in another), but not morph faces.